# Hilbert spaces and directed colimit

Tags: category-theory, hilbert-spaces

How to prove that a Hilbert space is the directed colimit of its finite-dimensional subspaces?

Does this imply that the category of Hilbert spaces (and bounded linear maps) is the Ind-completion (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ind-completion)) of that of finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces?

Comment: Maybe you can check by definition? Any $x$ in $\mathcal H$ is in particular in the f.d. subspace $<x>$, so given a collection of maps $(f_i:\mathcal H_i\to U)$ on the f.d. subspaces you have in particular $f_x:<x>\to U$, define $f:\mathcal H\to U$ by $f(x) = f_x(x)$. The fact that this is a direct colimit should give well-definedness and uniqueness.

Comment: (this might be too naive, as it proves that the category of all vector spaces and all linear maps is the ind-completion of finite vector spaces, in particular it doesn't show that $f$ is bounded)

Comment: @DanielTeixeira That's the whole point – the claim is false! Linear maps on finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces are automatically bounded, so if every Hilbert space were the colimit of its finite-dimensional subspaces then all linear maps on all Hilbert spaces would automatically be bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first: we need to be crystal-clear about what categories we are taking colimits in.
Let $\textbf{Hilb}$ be the category of complex Hilbert spaces and *bounded* linear maps and let $\textbf{Vect}$ be the category of complex vector spaces and linear maps.
(If you prefer, we can replace "complex" with "real" – it makes no difference to the argument.)

There is an evident forgetful functor $\textbf{Hilb} \to \textbf{Vect}$.
It is faithful, of course, but more is true: given Hilbert spaces $V$ and $W$, the map
$$\textbf{Hilb} (V, W) \to \textbf{Vect} (V, W)$$
is bijective if $V$ is finite-dimensional.
Hence, for any diagram $V : \mathcal{J} \to \textbf{Hilb}$ where each $V (j)$ is finite-dimensional, we have natural bijections
$$\textbf{Hilb} (\varinjlim V, W) \cong \varprojlim \textbf{Hilb} (V, W) \cong \varprojlim \textbf{Vect} (V, W) \cong \textbf{Vect} (\varinjlim V, W)$$
provided $\varinjlim V$ exists in both $\textbf{Hilb}$ and $\textbf{Vect}$.
The naturality of this bijection means that, if $\varinjlim V$ exists in $\textbf{Hilb}$ *and is preserved by the forgetful functor*, then $\varinjlim V$ has the property that every linear map $\varinjlim V \to W$ is bounded.
But this is impossible if $\varinjlim V$ is infinite-dimensional.
So either $\varinjlim V$ does not exist in $\textbf{Hilb}$ or is not preserved by the forgetful functor.

In particular, an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space is *not* the colimit of its finite dimensional subspaces: the underlying vector space is, so if the Hilbert space were also, then the colimit would be preserved by the forgetful functor.

Comment: +1. Would you have an idea about what colimits in $\mathsf{Hilb}$ do look like? Specifically if I took, say, $\ell_2(\Bbb C)$, and considered the colimit of its f.d. subspaces with the natural inclusion-based diagram, what might that be?

Comment: It is unclear to me which colimits do exist. Colimits of diagrams of finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces would have to be some kind of completion of the colimit of the underlying vector spaces.

Comment: I think that the category of Hilbert spaces with **linear contractions** (i.e., $\|T(x)\|\le\|x\|$) as morphisms has all colimits!

Comment: Yes, that category would probably have better properties. Banach spaces and linear contractions too.

Comment: Hilbert spaces with linear contractions give an $\omega_1$-accessible category. If that category had all colimits, it would even be $\omega_1$-presentable which is not possible, because it is self-dual.